# Alternators working parallel with a single neutral

Tags: electrical-engineering

I read a few articles on why neutral points of two alternators running parallel should not be connected to avoid circulating currents caused by difference in alternator windings and kind of understand its importance. But I could not quite appreciate the fact that the load would be shared equally by both generators since the neutral of one of the two generators is not in use.

Please help in understanding the concept.

Comment: Which articles? If you don't make clear which ones you have already we might suggest ones you already have which is a waste of your time and ours.

Comment: Well,  these are articles on paralleling of generators published by Cummins.

Comment: Is there a mechanical relation for what drives these generators?

Comment: These are Diesel Generators